# Jquery on click show/hide submenu not showing

Tags: jquery, click, show-hide, submenu

I have a menu hortizontal, with horizontal sub and subsub menu.
On click the sub menu should appear and stay visible. If I go to a page from the submenu, the sub sub menu should be visible.
I searched this site and the web for answers.

UPDATE

I'v modified the script, thanks to the answers you gave, that put me in the right direction and found a example here on stackoverflow.
The click is for tablets eo, for screens I like a hover. I tried to combine the script with a hover function, works.

```
    $('#menu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').show();
     },
     function() {
    $(this).find('ul').hide();
   });
```

Tried to combine the hover and click like this, but then the hover is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sub').hide();
$('#menu li a').on('click hover ', function(event){
if ($(this).next('ul.sub').children().length !== 0) {
event.preventDefault();
}
$(this).siblings('.sub').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
```

css

```
.sub{display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="item.php">Item</a></li>
 <li><a href="item1.php">item1</a>
   <ul class="sub">
   <li><a href="subitem1">subitem1</li>
        <ul class="subsub">
          <li> <a href="subsub1.php">subsub1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="subsub2.php">subsub2</a></li>
          <li> <a href="subsub3.php">subsub3</a></li>
        </ul></li>
   <li><a href="subitem2.php">subitem2</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
 //Hide all the sub menus
 $('.sub').hide();

 $('#menu li a').click(function(event){
if ($(this).next('ul.sub').children().length !== 0) {

}
 $(this).siblings('.sub').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what your goal is here.  Just to have sub-menu show up?  The second li contains a link.  If href has a value, you'll navigate to that page. So, sub-menu may show up, but you'll never see it.  Change href="#" and you should see your menu.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you want to access the submenu for item1.php. the jQuery will look something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('a', '#menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.sub').show();
    });
});
```

Here is [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSKYk/2/)

UPDATE 1: Mentioned in the comments below, user can not navigate actual links inside the menu. to fix this, add a class (I will use pageChange) to the links you want to to allow to change pages in the browser. to achieve this take my above code and bind it to your specified class. You will also need to add the class to the link tags too.

```
$(function() {
    $('a', '#menu').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('pageChange') === true) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.sub').show();
    });
});
```

Here is a new jsFiddle for above code: http://jsfiddle.net/pSKYk/3/

Comment: Great the submenu is showing on the item1 page, only all the other links are not working anymore.

Comment: If you add a class to the links that you want to access the menu js then you can choose which links are usable / dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate issue is setting a link to the menu options that show the submenus. When they're clicked, it will attempt to take you out of the page.

Here's a jsfiddle with it working (to my understanding). I also added toggle functionality, so it will hide the menu when clicked again: http://jsfiddle.net/9gcnm/1/

---

Also, just so ya know

```
$(function() {

});
```

is jQuery shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tryed your solution, works in jsfiddle but not in my site when I click item1, and that page is loaded, the sub menu is still not showing on that page. Should there also be a class on the li where I want the sub menu to display?